# How to use Scrapy-Splash

Tags: scrapy-splash

I try to use Scrapy to crawl a web whose URL will not change with the page go on.I used Splash to simulate CLICK .However ,it only take me to second page.I wonder how can I keep get next page and how to crawl web like that.

Comment: Do you need splash for scraping this webpage? In most cases, we don't need it.

Comment: What did you tried? Can you share some code with us?